# Location of newsletter sign up form on different browsers and computers

Tags: css, firefox, browser, safari

I previously got help from someone here on getting my newsletter sign up form to stay in the correct place in the header when minimizing the browser window. See here for reference: [How to make opt-in responsive so it stays in the correct place on smaller screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588128/how-to-make-opt-in-responsive-so-it-stays-in-the-correct-place-on-smaller-screen/20588314?noredirect=1)

After showing this to my client, she sees the fix, but she also sees the opt-in form positioned too low in the header so that it's below the space it's supposed to go in. She is on a Mac and she's viewing it on Safari. I'm on a PC laptop and I'm viewing it through Firefox. On mine, everything is positioned correctly, but on hers its off.

Now of course I put the exact top margin in so that it would show perfectly on my screen, but now I see it's off on hers, how do I adjust the code so that it shows where it's supposed to on all browsers?

I tried to add screenshots of what it looks like on both screens, but I need more reputation for that apparently. I also noticed that she says the sign up form is off using Firefox on her computer as well. Is there any way to fix this? Because again, I'm using Firefox and it's fine on mine. Here's the site: http://www.clearcreativecoaching.com/

Any help you can give will be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:** I figured it out! It was only showing a certain way for me when I was logged in. Once I logged out, I could see things the way my client did and was able to change it! Should I simply delete this post? I'm new here and want to be able to do things right and not junk up the place. Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: You have a malformed HTML structure.  If you want cross-browser consistency, you must follow the HTML standards.  It's so bad that the W3C validator stops cold.  See:  http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.clearcreativecoaching.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Just glancing at it real quick, looks like you have HTML like `<div>` elements inside your `head` section... probably caused by a misplaced `</head>` tag.

Comment: Hi @Sparky, I figured out my problem. Thanks for you input.

Comment: Then please help the community by posting the answer below.  Thanks.

Comment: Things were only showing differently when I was logged in. I noticed when I checked on all browsers (Firefox, Google Chrome, Internet Explorer and Safari) that the newsletter sign up form was not in the correct place. But when I was logged in, it was in the right place. So when I figured that out by logging out, I simply fixed the margin and it is now fixed on all browsers. So it wasn't really a browser issue at all. I believe because the code I was given from the other post had that top: 305px, the fact that the admin bar shows when logged in set that top position off. Does this make sense?

Comment: But you still have invalid HTML!   You cannot put div elements within the `<head></head>` section.  And that's not a browser issue either.

Comment: And I meant that you should post any solution as an answer below, not a comment here.

Comment: Hi Sparky, I am new here, so I wasn't aware of the "answer" area. I just added the answer properly. Thanks for the direction. As far as the invalid HTML. I added the divs in the header area of the site to customize it. This site is using a free Wordpress theme called Mantra. It's not really made to incorporate header elements like a sign up form. But I installed the Openhook plugin that gave me a header hook where I could place the desired html so I could get what I wanted for the site. My client wanted a sign up form in her header, and now she has one. The site is working fine now. Thanks.

Comment: You are confused.   The `head` section of the document  is not the `header` of your page.  The `<head>` of the HTML document is only for CSS, scripts, meta tags, etc.   Under no circumstances does page content ever go into the `<head>`.

Comment: Ok, I was calling it the incorrect name. You're right, it's the head, not header. Here is documentation from the Openhook Plugin wp_head hook: "Executes within your site’s head section." But the point is, I installed this plugin to specifically put code in there to have the newsletter sign up form show up where it is now. So although things may look broken or incorrect to you in the HTML, everything is working the way we want it. She has the sign up form where she wanted it and there are no other errors or problems showing on her site. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: You may _think_ it's correct, but [the W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html) and [the W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.clearcreativecoaching.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) say otherwise. The plugin scripts go in the `<head></head>`. The HTML for constructing the form go into the `<body></body>`. If the Wordpress plugin is causing this invalid HTML, then it's wholly defective and its inexperienced developer is very negligent.

Answer (score -1):

Things were only showing differently when I was logged in. I noticed when I checked on all browsers (Firefox, Google Chrome, Internet Explorer and Safari) that the newsletter sign up form was not in the correct place. But when I was logged in, it was in the right place. So when I figured that out by logging out, I simply fixed the top margin and it is now fixed on all browsers. So it wasn't really a browser issue at all. I believe because the code I was given from the other post had that top: 305px, the fact that the admin bar shows when logged in set that top position off.

Comment: Your code either follows the designated programming specifications or it doesn't.  [Yours clearly doesn't](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.clearcreativecoaching.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).   Once you gain enough experience to understand how everything works, you'll realize why this was broken and how your solution is only a temporary band-aide.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this information. As long as the site looks the way we want it to look for now, I'm not going to dig into this any deeper. If I run into any problems in the future I'll deal with them then. Thanks again for your help.